# Div and text changing together when hover

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, hover

I have a problem with my stylesheet (or maybe I need to use some JavaScript).

I have a div including an image and a text link. Both the image and the text links to another page.
When hovering over the image, the image opacity changes and the text color changes. That's perfect.
When hovering the text, only the text color changes, but I would like also the opacity of the image to change.

I can't find what's wrong with my CSS, or my HTML...

Here is my CSS:

```
.artists_menu{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}

.bandeau{
    height:7px; 
    background-color: #eeeeee
}

.cartouche_crop{
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity:1;
    webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cartouche_crop:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
    ilter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

h1 a:hover{
    color: magenta!important
}

a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

a:hover {
    color: magenta
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.amsbooking.fr/mattieumoreau/artists/amine_edge_and_dance/" title="amine edge &#038; dance">
    <div class="bandeau"></div>
    <div id="parent-57" class="parent-page">
        <div class="cartouche_crop">
            <img src="http://www.amsbooking.fr/mattieumoreau/wp-content/uploads/amine_11.jpg" class="artists_menu">
        </div>
        <div class="bandeau"></div>
            <h1>amine edge &#038; dance</h1>                
        <div class="bandeau"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is a jsFiddle link so you can see it live:
http://jsfiddle.net/FkWxb/1/

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: First of all: Don't just paste your unreadable code in here. Format it properly. No one can read it if everything sits on the same line. The post got edited, but keep this in mind for the future. While you're at it: Check your code for mistakes.

Comment: @kleinfreund I'm with you there. I hate it when people don't format their code...

Comment: @netcyphe There is a reason why the indentation of the HTML was the way I put it: There was an extra closing div which you removed. Edits should not fix code, but add proper formatting etc.

Comment: @kleinfreund Reviewing my earlier comment, I realize it was kind of ignorant. I shouldn't have removed the `<div>` tag, because code edits are supposed to take care of formatting and indentation like mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/FkWxb/3/

**replace** :

```
.cartouche_crop:hover{opacity:0.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);}
```

**by**

```
a:hover .cartouche_crop{opacity:0.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);}
```

**and remove**

```
h1 a:hover{color: magenta!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line into your css code `.parent-page:hover{opacity:0.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);}`

http://jsfiddle.net/XKe8L/

Comment: That works good, except that when you do that, it changes the text color, and then after about 250ms it changes the image opacity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enclosing both the text and the image in a div and applying the hover effect to the div.

I've wrapped the code in a div

```
<div id="fancy_hover">
<div class="cartouche_crop">
    <img src="http://www.amsbooking.fr/mattieumoreau/wp-content/uploads/amine_11.jpg" class="artists_menu">
</div>
```

and referenced it in the css

```
#fancy_hover:hover{opacity:0.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqVz4/

Comment: Jahnux73's answer destroys mine. Sleep is needed!